# How to put Admob ads on a unity Game?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, admob, ads, google-play-games

I have uploaded my game to the play store but haven't put ads yet its my first time and i am encountering many issues i am following many issues in this , Every time there is a new issue some time is says "Gradle failed to fetch dependencies" , sometimes a loading bar comes with heading "Resolving android Dependencies" and never goes and does not show any progress, and if i do the coding the games doesn't builds , can some one please help me throughout the process like what plugins I have to installs , Google play services , ads manager services all i am confused.

Answer (score 0):

**Unity3D** is a game engine that dedicated to software program to make games. It has features like 3d modelling, physics, camera. etc.
If you're going to use ***Visual Studio*** as your editor to develop a game using Unity3D, you can debug your code with **MonoDevelop** or use a third-party plug-in, **UnityVS**.

Based from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn759441.aspx):

> You can’t use Visual Studio as a debugger ***without UnityVS*** because when
>   you debug your game, you aren’t debugging `Unity.exe`, you’re debugging
>   a virtual environment inside of Unity, using a soft debugger that’s
>   issued commands and performs actions.

With UnityVS, you connect the Visual Studio back to Unity instead.

On the other hand, android studio is dedicated for android development. You can follow the starter for [Google Mobile Ads SDk for Unity](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start).

See for more details:

- [Android Development Setup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html)
- [Gradle Troubleshooting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-troubleshooting.html)